# delete a record and its FOREIGN key via a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints

I want delete an record by 'url' key match  in this table:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Articls 
        (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
            alias INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,                                 
            title VARCHAR(254) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,        
            url VARCHAR(2083) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,                      
            UNIQUE (alias),
            UNIQUE (title),
        )   DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci";
```

but After that I want delete all relative tags name in 'Tags' table too!

```
 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tags (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
            alias INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,    
            name VARCHAR(256) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL, 
            state INT(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, 
            created INT(11) NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (alias) REFERENCES Articls (alias)      
        ) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci";
```

Can I do it just with mysql query?

I do it with some php/mysql now:

1-get  alias where url = 'my url' in Articls.

2- delete all record in Tags table.

3. delete target record (where url = 'my url') in 'Articls' table.

Comment: Yes the delete query with join only will work if there is no foreign key constraints, you may use `on delete cascade`

Answer (score 0):

You should use 2 queries

```
DELETE FROM Tags
WHERE alias IN (SELECT id FROM Articls WHERE url = 'myurl.com')
;
DELETE FROM Articls WHERE url = 'myurl.com'
;
```

Or you can use cascade delete.

Instead:

```
FOREIGN KEY (alias) REFERENCES Articls (alias);
```

you need:

```
FOREIGN KEY (alias) REFERENCES Articls (alias) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

in this case each time when you delete row from Articls appropriate rows at Tags will be automatically deleted.